# No admin CSS following server switch

Tags: magento2

I've just copied an M2 site from one server to another.

Emptied var/

Emptied pub/static

Ran setup:static-content:deploy

Ran indexer:reindex

chown -R user:group *

The homepage and other pages work great.  The admin page is not loading any CSS for some reason.  The stylesheets are 404ing.  LEMP server.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix this all you need to do is redeploy for all languages your site is using, im assuming you are using GB so run the following

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
```

Once you have done this check the file/folder permissions also make sure your files have the correct group and owner

```
find * -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # for directories
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644 # for files
```

If this doesnt fix your issue then its possible one of your modules could be overwriting the admin theme i would check the **theme** table in the database to see if you have any other adminhtml themes you can find these by looking at are. if this is the case run the following and after flush your cache

```
php bin/magento module:disable Your_ModuleName
```